# Rotation in animation not working

Tags: unity, animation, rotation, transformation, import

I have a model of an SMG with arms exported from Blender and set to generic rig in unity import settings. I was creating an animation for this model in Unity Animation tab, it included changes in position and rotation of the individual parts like magazine and left arm and gun itself. Then when I was satisfied with how the animation worked (I saw it by pressing the play button IN THE ANIMATION TAB). My problem is that when I click play IN THE GAME TAB there is no rotation and some movement, only some parts move (but not rotate). Does anyone know what could be my problem? I am not sure what screenshots to post so tell me what you need to see and I'll add some.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are all the animation clips based off of one animation controller?

Comment: There is only one animation so far

Comment: And in the game when you are supposed to play the animation does it fire in the animator tab?

Comment: No it doesn't, the red line just stays at 0:00

Comment: Oh sorry I misread your comment, it does show me in the animator tab that the animation is playing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work. The problem was that I enabled "Apply root motion", when I disabled it the animation worked properly.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, saved me some time :)